# Is postgres 14 compatible with Django3.2.3 and Django framework 3.12.4?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework

I am using the following versions as of now

- Django Rest Framework is 3.12.4
- Python version is 3.9
- Django version is 3.2.3
- PostgreSQL 13.5

Is postgres 14 compatible with the above versions? I need to upgrade postgres to 14.

[Edit] Sorry had to remove the link to avoid confusion

thanks!

Comment: It's a release candidate - it's not likely that it's been certified for *anything* quite yet.

Comment: Posted On: Oct 19, 2021. You'd better check what they offer today, an RC is just a pre-release.

Comment: That is an old announcement. This [Postgres](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html) shows 14.1 and I'm guessing with recent release of the community 14.2 that will show up in the near future. As to support [Django 3.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/releases/3.2/) shows 9.6+. In any case you should set up a test environment to verify.

Comment: thanks all for replying. removed the AWS link to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and Postgress 14.2 is compatible with the following

- Django Rest Framework 3.12.4
- Python version 3.9
- Django version 3.2.3
- Psycopg 2.8.6

Comment: how did you check?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes